# Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSData?' to type 'NSData?'

Tags: post, swift, nsdata

I get this nonsense error where I try to attach the HTTPbody and I have not been able to find any answer while Googling.

```
func runRequest(url: String,arguments:String, method: String, closure: (NSData?, NSURLResponse, NSError?)->Void){
    var finalUrl:String
    var request:NSMutableURLRequest

    if (method == "POST"){
        finalUrl = url
        request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let data = (arguments as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.HTTPBody(data) // <-- Error here
    }else{
        finalUrl = url + arguments
        request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    }

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) in
        closure(data, response, error)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Just use : `request.HTTPBody = data`

Answer (score 2):

`HTTPBody` is a property, not a method.  You need to assign to it rather than call it:

```
request.HTTPBody = data
```

By the way, you probably want to change this to something safer:

```
NSURL(string: url)!
```

NSURL’s initializer is a “failable” initializer – that is, it returns an optional that might be `nil` if something went wrong (for example, the URL was malformed).  If that ever happens, `!` on that `nil` will cause your program to crash:

```
// fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
let url = NSURL(string: "blah blah blah")!
```